# How can I iterate through all possible grid layouts?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I have a grid (an `NSArray` of `CGPoint`s)where I want to layout some objects at points based on some constraints. This is what I know:

- How big the grid is
- The number of objects that have to be laid out on the grid, at a point
- The minimum distance between one object to another (calculated using some Pythagorean magic)
- The distance between points on a grid
- Each point can have only one object located there

I pick a random object (using `arc4random`) and validate whether or not this is a valid point. If it is, flag it as such and choose another point. If not, continue until either the entire array is searched at which point this grid layout is marked as impossible and start again.

This continues until a valid grid layout is found.

### Problem:

I don't know how many *if any* valid layouts exist for the given constraints. So I'm having trouble trying to find a way to either calculate the possible permutations, or iteratively search through the permutations to find if any valid grids exist, prior to embarking on an impossible search.

Comment: Some things aren't quite clear.  Do you have, for each pair of objects, a number giving the minimum allowable distance between those 2 objects?  And can more than one object appear at a single grid point?

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, there is a parameter the defines the minimum distances between objects (sorry, fixed the question) and only one object can appear at a single grid point. My particular problem is around laying out some trees randomly in an area, but also compensating for the maximum spread of the trees so as not to overlap.

Comment: OK, and is it the case that this minimum distance is the same for every pair of objects?  (I.e. there is just one parameter?)  And are the objects all indistinguishable?  (I.e. if we swapped the locations of object #1 and object #2, the result would be "unchanged"?)

Comment: If so, and if the minimum distance parameter is d, then (in the absence of a grid) the tightest way to place the objects would be to place them at the centres of circles of radius d/2 that are arranged in a hexagonal circle packing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing.  This isn't quite true for a finite region, but it's a good approximation, and you could get a good approximation of an optimum placement by choosing the grid points nearest to the centres.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, swapping object #1 and #2 would not change anything, so I guess to work out if it's even possible, I could calculate the area required by one object using the min distance parameter, multiply by the number of objects to layout and compare that to the total grid area - and compensate for not being concerned about the distance between the edge of the grid and the object (the distance restriction only applies between objects).

Comment: Yes, multiplying the circle area by the number of objects is a good lower bound.